# wildcard in a batch file using it as a text

Tags: batch-file

Is there any way to have a wildcard in a text for example,

```
:type
set menu=
set /p menu=type:
if /i "%menu%" == "go* north" goto north
```

Answer (score 0):

not possible with `if`, because it compares strings.

Try this instead of `if`:

```
echo %menu%|findstr /R /c:"go.* north">nul && goto north
```

PS: please don't ask, how to program AI in batch ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid I don't understand what is the supposed problem with this code:

```
@echo off

:type
set menu=
set /p menu=type:
if /i "%menu%" == "go* north" echo It works!
```

Example:

```
C:\> test.bat
type:go* north
It works!
```

You should realize that "the asterisk" is this character: `*`, and that "a wildcard" is when you insert an asterisk or a question mark *inside a file name*. You always can insert an asterisk or a question mark in a string as long as you don't use it as a file name.

If you want to check if a string *starts and ends with certain words*, you may do that this way:

```
if /i "%menu:~0,2%" == "go" if /i "%menu:~-5%" == "north" echo goto north
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo %menu%|findstr /b /e /i /r /c:"go.* north" >nul
if errorlevel 1 goto notnorth
:north
echo Go North!
```

should work to match any string starting `go` and ending <kbd>space</kbd>north`.

---

Here's he full test setup:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set menu=
set /p menu=type:

ECHO.&ECHO "%menu%" was input

echo %menu%|findstr /b /e /i /r /c:"go.* north" >nul
if errorlevel 1 goto notnorth
:north
echo Go North!

PAUSE
GOTO :eof

:notnorth
echo The input was NOT go North
ECHO I've no idea what you want to do under those circumstances.

PAUSE

GOTO :EOF
```

I put this in a file named `q24222234.bat`, then executed the command-line:

```
cls&echo go north|q24222234&echo go somewhat north|q24222234&echo go a bit north|q24222234&echo gomostly north|q24222234&echo go south|q24222234&echo go east|q24222234
```

which runs the batch file a number of times, entering the obvious string. The results were:

```
type:
"go north" was input
Go North!
Press any key to continue . . . 
type:
"go somewhat north" was input
Go North!
Press any key to continue . . . 
type:
"go a bit north" was input
Go North!
Press any key to continue . . . 
type:
"gomostly north" was input
Go North!
Press any key to continue . . . 
type:
"go south" was input
The input was NOT go North
I've no idea what you want to do under those circumstances.
Press any key to continue . . . 
type:
"go east" was input
The input was NOT go North
I've no idea what you want to do under those circumstances.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: what is the not north for? would this work for a list of commands.

Comment: That did not work, when I typed go it worked. When I typed go the north it ended the program.

Comment: It works ,but having a list of commands in the file defeats the purpose. The purpose was to a wildcard so that they could type whatever they want without having a list of commands.